# How to serialize method call expression with arguments?

Tags: c#, json, reflection, expression-trees

I have a call to a remote service which is described as following:

```
var user = new User { Name = "check" };
WcfService<IMyService>.Call(s => s.MyMethod(1, "param", user, new Entity { ID = 2 }));
```

In my `Call` method, I need to serialize this method call to JSON, which will be put in the WebSphere queue:

```
{
    "Interface": "IMyService",
    "Method": "MyMethod",
    "Arguments": [
        1,
        "param",
        {
            "Name": "check"
        },
        {
            "ID": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I know how to obtain interface and method names, but I cannot obtain non-constant values:

```
public static class WcfService<TInterface>
{
    public static void Call(Expression<Action<TInterface>> expr)
    {
        var mce = (MethodCallExpression)expr.Body;

        string interfaceName = typeof(TInterface).Name;
        string methodName = mce.Method.Name;

        var args = mce.Arguments
            .Cast<ConstantExpression>()
            .Select(e => e.Value)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

This code works for `1` and `"param"`, but does not work for `user` and `new Entity { ID = 2 })` since they are `FieldExpression` and `NewExpression` respectively. How to get the actual values, passed to a function call, instead of their expression representation?

**Update:** The answer from the [suggested duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457558/getting-values-from-expressiontrees) is not suitable, because I don't want to compile my expression and execute it - I only need to evaluate arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Values from ExpressionTrees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457558/getting-values-from-expressiontrees)

Comment: You can't get non constant values as they can be linked to closure or to method call parameters, and they will be evaluated during expression execution. So without knowing about them, it would be hard to get their actual values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have combined the information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13083397/3218692) and Pieter Witvoet's answer and received the following function:

```
public static object Evaluate(Expression expr)
{
    switch (expr.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.Constant:
            return ((ConstantExpression)expr).Value;
        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            var me = (MemberExpression)expr;
            object target = Evaluate(me.Expression);
            switch (me.Member.MemberType)
            {
                case MemberTypes.Field:
                    return ((FieldInfo)me.Member).GetValue(target);
                case MemberTypes.Property:
                    return ((PropertyInfo)me.Member).GetValue(target, null);
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException(me.Member.MemberType.ToString());
            }
        case ExpressionType.New:
            return ((NewExpression)expr).Constructor
                .Invoke(((NewExpression)expr).Arguments.Select(Evaluate).ToArray());
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException(expr.NodeType.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now, I can simply do the following:

```
var args = mce.Arguments.Select(ExpressionEvaluator.Evaluate).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

A `FieldExpression` has a `Member` (the field) and an `Expression`, in this case a `ConstantExpression` that holds the object that contains that field. Here the `Value` of that constant expression is an anonymous object that captures the local `user` variable. Casting `Member` to `FieldInfo` allows you to call `GetValue` on it, and by passing in the `Value` of that constant expression you'll get the `User` object you're looking for.

A `NewExpression` has a `Constructor` and an `Arguments` property (a list of expressions), but there is no value, because a new object is only produced when you actually invoke that function. You could compile that expression, invoke it and serialize the result, or you could serialize the constructor call itself - similar to how you are serializing that service call.

Note that `{ "Name": "check" }` and `{ "ID": 2 }` are missing type information.

Comment: It's ok that type information is missing since I will use reflection and deserialize them back according to the service method arguments' type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have [combined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36862531/3218692) your answer with another one and now everything works fine.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: Regarding type information, I assume you do not intend to support subclassing these argument types?